# Converting column names to variables in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing data from csv file and storing it in pandas dataframe. Here is the image from the csv file:

[image: example csv file]

For each row I want a string like this:

[image: output variables]

Here is the code I am using to import data from the csv file and storing it in the dataframe:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

filename ="../Desktop/venkat.csv"
df = pd.read_table(filename,sep=" ")
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
csvfile = open('test.csv','r')
csvFileArray = []
for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '\t'):
    csvFileArray.append(row)

header =csvFileArray[0][0].split(',')

str_list=[]
for each in csvFileArray[1:]:
    data= each[0].split(',')
    local_list = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        str_data =' '.join([header[i], '=', data[i]])
        local_list.append(str_data)
    str_list.append(local_list)

print str_list
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to use a `dict` to save your data with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

#select some row - e.g. with index 2
print (df.loc[2])
A    3
B    6
C    9
D    5
E    6
F    3
Name: 2, dtype: int64

d = df.loc[2].to_dict()
print (d)
{'E': 6, 'B': 6, 'F': 3, 'A': 3, 'C': 9, 'D': 5}

print (d['A'])
3
```

If ordering is important use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

print (OrderedDict(df.loc[2]))
OrderedDict([('A', 3), ('B', 6), ('C', 9), ('D', 5), ('E', 6), ('F', 3)])
```

If you need all values in columns use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.to_dict(orient='list')
print (d)
{'E': [5, 3, 6], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'F': [7, 4, 3], 
 'A': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [7, 8, 9], 'D': [1, 3, 5]}

print (d['A'])
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

```
d = df.to_dict(orient='index')
print (d)
{0: {'E': 5, 'B': 4, 'F': 7, 'A': 1, 'C': 7, 'D': 1}, 
1: {'E': 3, 'B': 5, 'F': 4, 'A': 2, 'C': 8, 'D': 3}, 
2: {'E': 6, 'B': 6, 'F': 3, 'A': 3, 'C': 9, 'D': 5}}


#get value in row 2 and column A 
print (d[2]['A'])
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(-1, 5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

   A  B  C  D  E
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8  9
```

You can get a series of `json` strings for each row

```
df.apply(pd.Series.to_json, 1)

0    {"A":0,"B":1,"C":2,"D":3,"E":4}
1    {"A":5,"B":6,"C":7,"D":8,"E":9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your csv is a comma delimited file.

```
import pandas as pd

filename ="../Desktop/venkat.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep=",")
output = df.to_dict(orient='records')

print output #this would yield a list of dictionaries
```